# Download uploaded files from Django Admin

Tags: django

I have uploaded some files in django admin using

```
File = models.FileField(upload_to='./list/')
```

Now I want to download the same file for which I have written the below function within the class :

```
def file_link(self):
    request = None
    full_url = ''.join(['http://', get_current_site(request).domain, self.cvFile.url])
    if self.cvFile:
        return "<a href='%s'>download</a>" % (full_url)
    else:
        return "No attachment"

file_link.allow_tags = True
```

However when I click on the link, it redirects to a page with the link appended to the present url. And since the url doesn't exist, it is showing error.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply do this

[Click to get the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41520310/5039197)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import *

class AppAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('author','title','file_link')
    def file_link(self, obj):
        if obj.file:
            return "<a href='%s' download>Download</a>" % (obj.file.url,)
        else:
            return "No attachment"
    file_link.allow_tags = True
    file_link.short_description = 'File Download'

admin.site.register(AppModel , AppAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an **absolute url** inside href, whereas `self.cvFile.url` will return a **relative url**. So unless you are on the home page, the link will simply append on to whatever url you are currently on. Simply add the domain url to `self.cvFile.url` and it should work.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Now I declared a new url : full_url = ''.join(['http://', get_current_site(request).domain, self.cvFile.url]). However its still redirecting to the same url as before.

Comment: And what is that url?

Comment: The link to the file appended with the current url.

Comment: Seeing the actual url would be helpful

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/app1/resourcestatic/ is the current url. When I click on the link to the uploaded file the link simply gets appended to it i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/app1/resourcestatic/cv/<cv_name>

Comment: Can you update the code in the question to what you are using now?

Comment: Use `pdb` to make sure the `domain` url and `self.cvFile.url` you get are as intended